# How do I change the material of a line renderer while it is a prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

first time asking a question on here, but I couldn't find my answer anywhere else. I'm relatively new to Unity and C#, but have experience coding in other languages.
I'm trying to make a drawing scene in my Unity2D game, where you can use your mouse to draw on a canvas, but am having trouble with switching colors. I set up the drawing, and it works pretty well. However, I want the player to be able to switch the color of the "ink" by pressing a button with their desired color on it, so I would have an orange, red, blue, green... etc.

I have tried many different ways of doing this, but am still stuck. Every time I press the button, it just spawns a line, and doesn't change the color.

This is the code I have now(which doesn't work):

```
public class ChooseColor : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Material mat;
    private Renderer rend;

    private void Start()
    {

        GameObject prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Assets/Assets");
        rend = prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        rend.material = mat;
    }
}
```

This has frustrated me and I hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: What is it you think you would achieve by that? Why not change the material rather after spawning an instance of the prefab on the Instances? Alternatively: you can also directly change the color on the material -> this way all users of the same material would directly be affected .. no need to have multiple materials then

Comment: In general on the prefab you can try to rather change the `sharedMaterial` instead.. not sure if this will work outside of the editor though

Comment: I solved this somehow(forget how i did)